# Sending an email upon system shutdown

Tags: python, windows, flask, background-process, shutdown

I'm running a flask app, but the server it's running on has mandatory system updates and restarts that I cannot disable. I'm also not able to use auto-login, so I can't just have the app restart on it's own after a system update. I figure the best way to handle this is to send myself an email before the system restarts so I at least know I'll need to manually login again.

What's the best way to do this? I just want to send an email when the program recieves a shutdown signal.

Comment: Bro we need more info to be able to help you. More specifically code. And the name of the server you're running it on.

Comment: You need to write a Service or Start Up Script there is No good way to send an e-mail when a Server restarts, because it could be that the Code for Email Sending is Not executed completly because of the Server shutdown. It Sounds a Bad Idea 